# Remove item from Javascript array on change

Tags: javascript

I have a bit of situation. Basically I am adding an item to JavaScript array, which I am populating on select box change. But the problem is when I input 0, it should removed from an array.

Here is the code

```
var addon = new Array();
function updateAddons(){
    addon.length=0;

    var plan = new Array;
    var planQty = new Array;

    plan.length=0;
    planQty.length=0;

    for(var j =0 ; j< 3; j++){
        $("select[name='addon_"+j+"[]'] option:selected").each(function(){
            var item = {
                product_name : $(this).attr('pn'),
                product_cost : $(this).attr('cost'),
                product_id : $(this).val()
            };
            if(item.product_id != 0){
                plan.push(item);
            }
        });
        $("input[name='addonQty_"+j+"[]'] ").each(function(){
            if($(this).val() != 0){
                planQty.push($(this).val());
            }
        });
    }

    for(var i =0; i < plan.length; i++){
        var item = {
            product:plan[i],
            product_qty:planQty[i]
        }
        if(item.product.product_id != 0){
            addon.push(item);
        }

    }

}
```

I have created a jsfiddle [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/hfu5S/) to view that. (check your browser console for the complete object.)

If someone can help. And please explain your answer.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. put a artibitary number in place of 0 and not adding in the final array.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with you code is the following statement:

```
 if($(this).val() != 0)
```

The problem is if the input is empty the value is `undefined`. In javascript `undefined` is not equal to `0`. An easy way to solve this is to test for undefined as well:

```
 if($(this).val() != 0 && $(this).val() != undefined)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But now I am facing another issue, and the problem is that while adding item to array it if product id is 0 it breaks the array and cannot add item next to it.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain I have created an updated JSFiddle to show what i would do to get it to work (logs to console after each update) http://jsfiddle.net/hfu5S/1/

Comment: Thanks. But now select any item from second dropdown and input 3 in the respective textbox. Now you will know what problem I am facing.